# Minimum Subset within Correlation Matrix

Tags: correlation-matrix

I have a correlation matrix that I produced in Excel using the monthly returns from 200 different trading systems over a X year period.  So, the correlation matrix is 200 rows by 200 columns.  How do I now go about determining the best combination of 10 systems that would give me the lowest correlated subset (i.e., lowest potential of aggregate sum of correlation values in a 10x10 correlation matrix)?  Also, can this be done in Excel?  Thanks.

Comment: Some form of factor analysis, maybe a singular value decomposition could be a start?

Comment: Mabye this is useful: http://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/2263/how-to-cluster-stocks-and-construct-an-affinity-matrix?rq=1